# list of object to single selected object on submit form button razor mvc c#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

i have razor view with List. but on submit button i want to send selected Employee[0] or any other index Employee[1] to respected controller.

let suppose.

```
 @model List<Employee>

@for(int i=0;i<Model.Count;i++)
{
        @using (Html.BeginForm("A", "B", FormMethod.Post, 
                         new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
       {
        @html.TextBoxFor(x=>x[i].Name);
        <input id="abc" type=submit>
       } 
}


 public Acontroller()
{
    public ActionResult B(Employee employee)
    {
      employee.Name.....
    }
}
```

Comment: `i<Model.Count`? Right?

Comment: You code would not even compile! The textbox would need to be `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].Name)` because the model is a collection. but this makes no sense. You can only submit one form so why are you generating all that extra pointless html. And then what happens when a user enters a value in one textbox and then clicks another submit button

Comment: Your going about this the wrong way (and it will not work anyway). Have an index view to display all your objects, with associated Edit links to redirect to an Edit page to edit that `Employee`. Or if you want to edit one or more employees in a view then you have one form and a `for` loop inside it to generate the html for each item, and you post back the whole collection.